# Which online color correction services give good results?

Tags: color-correction, service-recommendation

I have a photo with some problems, like washed out colors, overexposure and a bit of blurriness. I tried to fix it myself in photoshop but that didn't go very well. I also tried an online service I found in a google search but the result I got was terrible.

I would appreciate if you have a recommendation for an online color correction service that you got good results from.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's not your monitor? Also, there is really no way to fix blurriness.

Comment: @Fake Name, I use the factory settings of my monitor. Most photos I see look great, but not mine. For blurriness, the unsharpen filter in photoshop can take care of that, but the main problem I have at the moment is the colors.

Comment: It's hard to imagine how such a service could operate, given that they don't know how the colors should look like in real life. Also,  overexposed data is quite impossible to restore, unless you have negative film or you haven't yet tried to export underexposed image from RAW.

Comment: @Imre. There are already tons of such services, I'm just looking for a good one. Some examples are deepetch.com, fotofix.com, colorati.com, photographersedit.com and a lot others

Comment: My bad, I forgot it doesn't have to look 100% real to look good. Well, availability of such services is good news for me, learning all the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The ones I am familiar with are more established companies rather then fly by night shops that just setup a website one day and shut down the next. They also are mainly setup for professional studios that burn through many shoots a year, and are looking to outsource some of the "tedious" work we all know as photography :)

**[Shoot Dot Edit](http://shootdotedit.com) and [Lavalu](http://www.mylavalu.com)** are the two big shops that I know people are using in the industry. They basically take all of the steps off your hands after you capture the images, to where you can send the proofs to the client. They will cull, color correct, enhance, crop, and process all of your images to what they call "dialed into your style".

I'm not sure if you can try these services as a one off image and a standard consumer. Honestly you could probably upload the image somewhere, and ask here in chat, and someone could edit it for you for free. But if you are more serious about outsourcing your editing work, try the above mentioned services.

Comment: Thanks dpollitt for your great answer. Unfortunately it's only one photo in my case, so it seems it's going to be harder to get it done. I don't really want to annoy anyone with my problem so I'm not so sure about uploading the photo, but thanks for the suggestion anyway. It seems the really good services mostly work with studios, not individuals (which of course makes sense, financially speaking). So, I'm only left with the option of trying another service I find online, which I already have (now waiting to see the results). I just hope I don't spend too much money in this hit and miss thing!